# IntelliJ Spring Boot: How to create an executable jar

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, jar, spring-boot, executable-jar

I'm trying to create an executable jar from IntelliJ.

First I got the Java Security Exception and I changed `sqljdbc4-4.0` to `unsigned`. First problem **solved**.

Then I got Manifest not found. Added `META-INF` dir to output. Second problem **solved**.

Next I got the `BeanCreationException` (**unsolved**):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
```

In IntelliJ it is working.

I think the resources are not in the output. (`application.properties`, ...)

[image: IntelliJ Config]

In which way do I add the resources or where are they stored in the jar.

I'm using `gradle` and on the spring boot homepage are only instructions for maven.

Comment: How did you create the project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` or `spring-boot-gradle-plugin`, depending on your preferred build system.

**EDIT:**

Just run `./gradlew build`

I suggest to dive into this [getting started guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/). It clarifies a lot of stuff for beginners.

Comment: I've gradle. In Spring boot docu I only found maven and I haven't used this build mode before. Can you please be more in detail?

Answer (score 5):

A typical Spring boot project is a Maven project or a Gradle-Project (I only know how to do it with Maven, for Gradle see [luboskrnac`s answer][1]). So you just need to run the maven target`package`and pick the jar form the (created)`target` folder

use a shell, go to the project root directory (where the `pom.xml` file is) and type

```
mvn clean package
cd target
```

the there is the xxx.jar file.